# How to create a record when it depends on another record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have 2 models, each of them depend on another.

```
class Company < ActiveRecord
  belongs_to :user
end

class User < ActiveRecord
  belongs_to :company
end
```

The company has a required user_id column.
The user has a required company_id column.

**How can I create a company and user when they both depend on each other?**

Answer (score 1):

In your scenarion this relationship is called `many to many relationship`, You can create middle table between this called `users_companies` with foreign key of both table

For more details please refer this link [Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html)

Like example

```
class Company < ActiveRecord
  has_many :users_companies, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :users, through: users_companies
end

class User < ActiveRecord
  has_many :users_companies, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :companies, through: users_companies
end

class UsersCompany < ActiveRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :company

  # This model have two foreign key
  user_id and company_id
end
```

Comment: I think the join table should be companies_users, both plural. In an alphabetical order. http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#creating-join-tables-for-has_and_belongs_to_many-associations

Answer (score 0):

Use a dummy value to fake one of the object is valid

```
company=Company.create(user_id: dummy)
user=User.new
user.company = company
user.save
company.update_attribute(user_id: user.id)
```